# ion-select overflow when limiting the app width and center content in Ionic 6

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, webview, scss-mixins

I'm doing a mobile application in **Ionic v6** and we want to deploy it as a web app as well (desktop version).

When we open the app in a web browser, by default, the app takes all the width available in the screen and for us is a little ugly and reduce the user experience.

Example:

[image]

To limit the width on desktops and center the content we followed advices found on these topics:

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-limit-ionic-app-width/96785/7
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-detect-device-to-change-the-display-of-body/118831

```scss
// global.scss
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

The result is good:

[image]

While testing the app, menus, popovers, etc.. we have found that all `ion-select` overflows the screen and all the content is moved to the left. Example:

[image]

I have tried:

```scss
// global.scss
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

html {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The result is the same.

The expected result is:

[image]

My goal is to center the app and limit its width, while ensuring that all ion-select, popover, etc.. presents correctly.

Any advice would be appreciated.